# NSURLConnection http request call refresh from applicationWillEnterForeground method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

My app is a location based app and it works good. Now I want to refresh the information when I come from Background. I called one function from `AppDelegate` method it calls `NSURLConnection` request and get information successfully for one place which is first give. But not get refreshed for other places I assigned.

code is:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

  [self.viewController refresh];//api refresh method.
}
```

Now it send the request for first I assigned place even it changed but not get modify the `UIViewController` details.

Here I want refresh the request for last I gave place. But I takes and work for first place only. Wow can i solve this problem.

Comment: show the code of refresh. It only gets called one time so obviously we can't see why there are not multiple requests.

Comment: NSString *strs=[@"http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",place.latitude,place.longitude]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strs]];
     NSLog(@"%@",request);
    self.reqTimeZone=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [self.reqTimeZone start];                                            This is my request it calls for old place request only when i  am refresh from Appdelegate method.

Comment: @user1278712, please edit your answer instead of adding the code as a comment

Comment: strs has a semi-colon in the call `;` remove it and i believe it will work.

Comment: Thank for replay that is works good. now i want to call the above NSURLconnection request from applicationWillEnterForeground:. It sends request for old one. for example first i get information for San-francisco now i went background and come back it calls for San-fransisco and display the info.then i changed the place to "Chennai" its not get refresh from  applicationWillEnterForeground:.it calls for San-fransisco and get info. but not update. this is a problem i hope you understand thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are receiving data , the second time you hit the url nad it is not being reflected in the viewcontroller then there might be problem as :-
1>At what Event you might want to refresh data.
2>How are you sending the data to another viewcontroller
Check if the data is reaching the intended viewcontroller successfully
```

.

Also please show your refresh method.
If your refresh method has some parameters and you are not sending those parameters then you may try:-

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 
{     
NSLog(@"app will enter foreground");     
[viewController refresh:NULL]; 
}
```

If the problem persists please post your code.

Comment: i did not send any parameter to viewController because the refresh method nothing follow                                                   -(void)refresh{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.placedetail.name);
    [self displays:self.placedetail];
}                                                                    placedetails is a object has place info for send request. in displays method sends request using place details. it works well and get refresh for one place which is first time assign place. second time sends request for old place only not for new one. please help me how can i refresh for all place